# Create Table in mysql from c#

Tags: c#, mysql

I wantto create table, but my code isn`t correctly. Plese tell me - where I mistake.
Thank you!

```
MySqlCommand Create_table= new MySqlCommand("CREATE TABLE 123 (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,action VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id)) COLLATE='utf8_general_ci' ENGINE=InnoDB;",con);
Create_table.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the name of the table `123`.
It contains only digits and from [MySql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/identifiers.html)

> Identifiers may begin with a digit but unless quoted may not consist
>   solely of digits.

You need to enclose the table name within backticks or start the name with a letter

```
MySqlCommand Create_table= new MySqlCommand(@"
        CREATE TABLE `123` 
        (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        action VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, 
        PRIMARY KEY (id)) COLLATE='utf8_general_ci' ENGINE=InnoDB;", conn);
Create_table.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I suggest to change that name to avoid future problems of the same kind